# Android OnClickListener - memory leak?

Tags: android

If I'm not statically creating the OnClickListener like below, since we're not removing the onClickListener, does this create a reference to the Activity and therefore cause a memory leak?

```
findViewById(R.id.custom).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do whatever

            }}) ;
```

Or, does it not create a leak because it's a circular reference?

Comment: why do you think that you have a circular reference?

Comment: Activity owns button, button has a listener that is owned by Activity, if both can't be accessed from root, then theoretically they should be GCed.

Comment: No, because there is no circular reference in Java, check my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74786304/3753336