# Local onclicklistener does this cause memory leak

Tags: android

Does defining an "onclicklistener" like this cause a memory leak due to a reference to the current Activity? (i.e. does the `currentActivity.this` mention create a strong reference to the current Activity, hence preventing it from being garbage collected?)

```
public class currentActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

            // setup

            myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, newActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be fine as the activity owns the button and the button owns the click listener, if the activity gets destroyed it will in turn kill the button and its click listeners.

It would be a memory leak if for example you passed the activity to a singleton object and kept it as a reference e.g.

```
object SomeObject {
   var activity: AppCompatActivity? = null
}

public class currentActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // setup

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SomeObject.activity = this
                Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, newActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

at the point the activity is destroyed the Singleton will keep a reference to the activity that is about to be destroyed and cause a leak.

Comment: ok thanks! but the clicklistener then owns a reference to the activity (currentActivity.this) so this leads to a circular reference?

Comment: No because GC should pick up its no longer required due to the scope of the function being finished when startActivity is called, also consider when GC will try and garbage collect the activity, which is when it is destroyed, which based on your code is when the click listener is called i.e. a new activity is launched

Answer (score 1):

No, because garbage collection on JVM is not based on reference counting (as it is on iOS), but on ["mark-sweep" GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection).

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/what-memory-leak-java) **memory leak in Java is a situation where some objects are not used by application any more, but GC(garbage collector) fails to recognize them as unused**

1. If you make any `View` or `Activity` or `Application` *static* or pass them in a manner it will hamper their regular lifecycle or something similar, it would be considered memory leak
2. or registering to a listener, that could be called back even if the activity is destroyed, it will also create memory leak
3. etc

In your case, if your activity is destroyed, the callback can easily be garbage collected as, their scope is within this activity